# Jmeter - analysis of the performance test

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing, analysis

How can I understand that my server is doing fine?

I did some performance testing and the result was like:

No Of Sample: 750

Latest Sample: 3317

Average: 601

Deviation : 1152

Throughput: 2613.24

Median: 386

what are these parameters mean?

how can I give correct inputs and expect correct result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that [JMeter Glossary](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/glossary.html) can explain all the terms.

Just in case if it goes away:

- `No of Sample` - total number of samples executed.
- `Latest sample` - self-explanatory
- `Average` - [Arithmetic_mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_mean) of all samplers execution time: sum of all samplers duration divided by the "No of Sample"
- `Throughput` - number of requests per time unit, like hits per second
- [Median](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median) and [Deviation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deviation_(statistics)) - are statistical terms

In regards to whether your server behavior is acceptable or not - it depends on what it is doing. 601 ms average response time sounds very good for i.e. online shop, but it may be not acceptable for finance operations, medical equipment or NASA spaceships. Besides it is quite unclear how many concurrent users were involved into load test as it were 2-5 virtual users the application under test may behave good, and in case of 20-50 concurrent users response time will get 60 seconds - that would be bad.

See [Performance Metrics for Websites](https://docs.blazemeter.com/customer/portal/articles/1932764-performance-metrics-for-websites) guide to learn about the most common measures which need to be done during performance testing.

Comment: In my test, there were 50 concurrent users and 3 times loop.